# How to get which user has created a revision of a resource?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I can get all revisions of a resource `my_resource`

```
$ helm history my_resource
```

It gives me an output

```
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART               DESCRIPTION     
1           Thu Jun 2  11:25:22 2018    SUPERSEDED  my_resource-1.0.0   Install complete
2           Mon Jun 6  15:11:50 2018    SUPERSEDED  my_resource-1.0.1   Upgrade complete
3           Tue Jun 11 18:40:55 2018    SUPERSEDED  my_resource-1.0.2   Upgrade complete
4           Thu Oct 9  16:12:45 2018    DEPLOYED    my_resource-1.0.3   Upgrade complete
```

Is there any way to get a username/account which created a specific revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `helm` tracks deployed releases using component Tiller that is installed in `kube-system` namespace.
It has the following jobs:
-   Answer requests from Helm clients
-   Expand and render charts into a set of Kubernetes resources
-   Manage releases

When we run `helm list`, Tiller shows us all of the releases. And we can use `helm history` to see all of the revisions for a given release.
`Tiller` stores all of this information in Kubernetes ConfigMap objects. And those objects are located in the same namespace as Tiller.

Release list:

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system -l "OWNER=TILLER"
 NAME           DATA            AGE  
 elastic1.v1    1               57m


kubectl get configmap -n kube-system -l "OWNER=TILLER" -o yaml   

  kind: ConfigMap   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: 2018-10-05T08:54:50Z
     labels:
       MODIFIED_AT: "1538731409"
       NAME: elastic1
       OWNER: TILLER
       STATUS: DEPLOYED
       VERSION: "1"
     name: elastic1.v1
     namespace: kube-system
     resourceVersion: "103223"
     selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/elastic1.v1
     uid: 5170941d-c87c-11e8-aa86-42010a840002 kind: List metadata:   resourceVersion: ""   selfLink: ""
```

Good article: [click here](http://technosophos.com/2017/03/23/how-helm-uses-configmaps-to-store-data.html)

Also, there is an open proposal on GitHub to add an additional label like release owner into `helm ls` command: [github](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2734)

Hope it will help you in further investigations.